# how to simply import a groovy file in another groovy script

Tags: groovy

```
~/groovy
 % tree
.
├── lib
│   ├── GTemplate.class
│   └── GTemplate.groovy
└── Simple.groovy


class GTemplate {
  static def toHtml() {
    this.newInstance().toHtml1()
  }
  def toHtml1() {
    "test"
  }
}


import lib.*
class Simple extends GTemplate {
}
```

**Error:**

> % groovyc Simple.groovy 
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Compilation incomplete: expected to find the class
>   lib.GTemplate in /home/bhaarat/groovy/lib/GTemplate.groovy, but the
>   file contains the classes: GTemplate 1 error

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you are confusing Groovy with PHP-like techniques.

Because it's closer to Java, if a class exists within a subfolder, it needs to exist within a package of the same name.  In your example, you could add this line to the top of `GTemplate.groovy` and recompile the file:

```
package lib
```

However, this means that the fully-qualified name for GTemplate is now actually `lib.GTemplate`.  This may not be what you want.

Alternatively, if you want to use the files from a subfolder without using packages, you could remove the `import` statement from `Simple.groovy`, and instead compile and run the class like so:

```
groovyc -classpath $CLASSPATH:./lib/ Simple.groovy
groovy -classpath $CLASSPATH:./lib/ Simple
```

> *NOTE: If you don't have a `CLASSPATH` already set, you can simply use:*
>
> ```
> groovyc -classpath ./lib/ Simple.groovy
> groovy -classpath ./lib/ Simple
> ```
>
> *Also, for windows machines, change `$CLASSPATH:` to `%CLASSPATH%;`*

I *strongly* recommend learning about packages and understanding how they work. Look at this [Wikipedia article on Java packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) for a starting point.