# Groovy importing static nested classes

Tags: groovy

The following two classes in the same package:

Imported.groovy

```
class Imported {
  static class Inner {
  }
}
```

Main.groovy

```
import Imported

class Main {
  static main(args) {
    new Imported.Inner()
  }
}
```

When run:

```
$ groovy Main.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/tmp/Main.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class Imported.Inner
 @ line 5, column 5.
       new Imported.Inner()
       ^

1 error
```

Any reason this is happening? How to properly import static nested classes?

Answer (score 0):

Just compile `Imported.groovy`: `groovyc Imported.groovy` so that you have `Imported.class` and `Imported$Inner.class`.

Then simply invoke `groovy Main.groovy` and it should work.

If you want to have some "import/include" functionality, check [Including a groovy script in another groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136328/including-a-groovy-script-in-another-groovy) and [how to simply import a groovy file in another groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738118/how-to-simply-import-a-groovy-file-in-another-groovy-script).

Comment: Thanks jalopaba. Why is compilation necessary here? E.g. `new Imported()` works without compiling. Also, this won't be a workable solution when using `groovysh`.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in the compilation process of the script, but I'm not sure. Inner classes have usually been a problem in groovy.

Comment: If the nested class was already compiled? I'm using a 3rd party lib.